# apache + nginx ssl ciphers to enable / disable in 07/2016

Tags: apache, ssl, nginx

on the one hand i would like to disable as many (weak) ciphers as possible but on the other hand don't want to exclude too many users.

So i read much stuff and saw many examples. Some of them are outdated, some seem wrong and some seem ok.

I finally came out with this (Apache 2.4):

```
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
```

The sslscan result is

```
Preferred TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384   Curve P-256 DHE 256
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384       Curve P-256 DHE 256
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384     DHE 2048 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA            DHE 2048 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA          Curve P-256 DHE 256
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA          Curve P-256 DHE 256
Preferred TLSv1.1  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA            DHE 2048 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.1  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA          Curve P-256 DHE 256
Accepted  TLSv1.1  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA          Curve P-256 DHE 256
Preferred TLSv1.0  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA            DHE 2048 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.0  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA          Curve P-256 DHE 256
Accepted  TLSv1.0  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA          Curve P-256 DHE 256
```

The Qualys SSL Scan result for our site is an A+. As far as i can see just very old OS/Browser combinations will have problems with our site.

Question1: Should i enable more than the ciphers above? If so, why?

Question2: Should i disable ciphers, i have got in my list? If so, why?

Thanks,

Bjoern

Answer (score 0):

This trade-off is something that you'll need to evaluate yourself, depending on the clients you're targeting.

We too have an A+ rating and the only browser it doesn't support is IE 6, and Java 6u45 client.

Comparing your security to the likes of popular social networks and banks is a good start, but the tweaking is your call.

Check this [generator from Mozilla](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/) for standard Modern, Intermediate, and Old configs.